# RavenDb vs CouchDb in Memory Management Approaches

Tags: couchdb, redis, ravendb

RavenDB (a .Net JSON storage storage db with querying) provides aggressive caching / memory management under its own control (via its own storage engine Munin), with config parameters to tweak various cache sizes etc... Google groups suggests that before (may not be the case with latest releases) occasional out-of-memory exceptions as result of un tuned parameters (with sufficient size db / index).

CouchDB seems to take a different approach and leaves the caching to the operating system. Meaning when I GET /db1/doc-id-1 it essential in terms of programming a file read op against the filesystem which the OS can optimize away due to its own caches. Similarly I believe this is same for views and of reduce results (multiple parts of b tree need loading/computed from disk depending on range).

The latter seems superior to me, the OS have gone from years of evolutions in caching/paging etc.. and pressure from other services can balance memory.

Firstly. 
Am I correct in my understanding?
Is CouchDB's approach unique to Unix based OSes (although I see they have a Windows port)?
Is there a reason a .Net DB cant relying on the OS to optimize away file reads etc..? 
What are the disadvantages and advantages of each approach that would influence choice in building a data store?

Side note: I believe Redis is the same just keeping the index in memory, each GET KEY is a disk hit (which either does hit the disk heads or not depending on the OS file caching)

Answer (score 2):

Jia93,
One of the reasons that we are working the way we do is that we have stronger separation between the layer. CouchDB have much the same optimizations as we do (keeping things in mem), but it is doing that on top of the BTree structure that is directly expose to the application.

Another reason for caching the results is to avoid the costs of parsing the json on every single request.

Comment: CouchDB makes heavy use of the OS filesystem cache for performance, whilst I see RavenDB explicitly caches stuff in its own process space. So when there is pressure on system (from other processes, mysql, apache, IIS etc..) the OS filesystem cache is reduced but the memory usage for CouchDB remains constant.

Comment: I can see the benefit from avoiding json parsing from the RavenDB method

Comment: Does .Net/RavenDB provide hooks to detect when resources are tight to reduce caches, or does it use a soft/weak ref system?